# Command using lettrine affects all paragraphs

Tags: indentation, lettrine

I'm completely new to LaTeX. I found a template and it creates a command using the lettrine package:

```
%An initial of the very first character of the content
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand{\initial}[1]{%
    \lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,nindent=0em]{
        \color{gray}
            {\textsc{#1}}}{}}
```

So I use it at the beginning of my chapter like this:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:100}

\initial{I}ndustry 4.0 is a wide...
```

The result is fine:
[image: First letter]

The problem is now, that all paragraphs within the chapter are affected as well, because the first three lines of each new paragraph, for example after a list, is indent.

[image: Paragraph effected]

If I don't use the "initial" command it looks fine.

The problem is, that even \noindent doesn't work.
How can I deactivate this behaviour for the rest of the chapter?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! that be more clear, that is your problem, please provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{,,,}` and ending with `\end{document}`. use `\letrine  hasn't work with lists.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue; please, make a compilable example.